# Explorer hangs after installing Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer

After installing Internet Explorer, my Windows and Explorer hangs, my system crashed and only Task Manager is available.

Comment: reboot your system. What version of Windows & Internet Explorer ?

Comment: when reboot system only task manager available

Comment: my problem is solved restart in safe mode and type in run command appwiz.cpl and go to add remove program and uninstall internet explorer and restart windows

Answer (score 3):

Can you run `explorer.exe` from Task Manager via the File | Run menu of Task Manager?

If you can't get explorer to run, you likely have a corrupt Windows install and should reinstall Windows (if in XP) or do a repair install (if in Vista or Windows 7).

Comment: i can not repair in 7

Comment: @jozi sure you can see http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html